# Linq Get Latest Date Query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, datetime, asp.net-mvc-4, max

I am trying to get the latest date based on my controller below but I was hit with this error :

"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType20`1[System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]]]' to type 'System.IConvertible'."

```
       var latestDt = from n in db.Books
                       where n.id == id
                       select new { Date = n.dtBookBorrowed};


        DateTime dtPlus1Year = Convert.ToDateTime(latestDt);
```

May I know how do I get just the column latestDate in linq?

Comment: Types are paramount in C#. What is the type of `latestDt`? Why do you think that type can't be converted to `DateTime`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can try this to get list of date order by latest insert to db.**

```
var latestDt = db.Books.Where(n => n.id == id).OrderByDescending(x => x.dtBookBorrowed).Select(x => x.dtBookBorrowed).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use

```
DateTime.Parse(item.dateAsString)
```

your problem should be solved.

Comment: Why do i need to parse it as string since I need it in datetime?

Comment: thats just what the DateTime class wants as an input parameter, and as an out parameter you will get the date time you want. It shouldn't be a big problem to get from var to string.

Answer (score 0):

The LINQ query expression you've defined returns a collection of anonymous object with property `Date` despite there might be only one record match as ID was meant to be unique.

In your case we only need the target field that can be parsed as `DateTime` and therefore an alternative in fluent syntax would be as following:-

```cs
var book = db.Books.SingleOrDefault(book => book.id == id); // gets matching book otherwise null

if (book != null)
{
  var borrowedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(book.dtBookBorrowed);  
}
```

Otherwise if you would like to understand more about the behaviour with query syntax which may return multiple results, you may simplify as following which returns collection of `DateTime` object (i.e. `IEnumerable`) instead:-

```cs
IEnumerable<DateTime> borrowedDates =
  from n in db.Books
  where n.id == id
  select Convert.ToDateTime(n.dtBookBorrowed);
```